Additional Pro Tem Needed — Who would like to Moderate this site?
I am pleased to announce that 'egreg' has agreed to fulfill the role of pro tem moderator for this site.

Congratulation!

original post
Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, I need to appoint another provisional Moderators to help moderate this site. 
Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
The Nomination Process:

Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
Self nominations are encouraged. This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the --- markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:
We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

Have been consistently active in the site's activitie;
Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

<h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>

<h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>

Notes:

<why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>

---

(this section is edited in by the nominee)
I accept/decline this nomination

I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
want to know about me are…

etc.



If there aren't self-nominations for a while, I think we should start to propose people. It may be easier that way for some people to make one's own decision.

Since there hasn't been self-nominations for an amount of time, I'll make some proposals. Please add your proposals if you feel that other people can do this task.

Charo, Thank you. I was getting worried since a lack of folks willing to step up to moderate is just about the only thing that can get a site shut down.

@egreg: Congratulations and welcome to the Mod team!

egreg: 
Meta Profile
Notes:

He's been a very active user since this site's creation.
He has participated in Meta, showing interest in building this community.
He visists the site very frequently.
He leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything he writes.
He has completed several review tasks.
He is very interested in improving the quality of this site.

EDIT
I accept the nomination

DaG:
Meta Profile
Notes:

He's been a very active user since this site's creation.
He has participated in Meta, showing interest in building this community.
He visists the site very frequently.
He leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything he writes.
He has completed several review tasks.
He is very interested in improving the quality of this site.


DaG here. Thanks a lot, but I am not able to accept this nomination.
As I have also explained to a SE representative who wrote to me, while I spend quite a bit of time on this site, it is just in the odd moments within a lot of other commitments, and I can't really take on another responsibility, even though SE sites are a great resource I use and love.
